# Trying to remove html format from source in DataFrame

Tags: python, html, string

I have a dataframe containing the source for the tweets. The source is in the following format:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>
```

I am trying to find a way to strip the html and keep the url. I'm not very familiar with Regex and can't really find a solution.
any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the url by making the tag a [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) object.
If it is already a BeautifulSoup object then you can apply this directly

```
.find("a").get("href")
```

If not then you can make it a BeautifulSoup object.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #pip install beautifulsoup4

a_tag ='<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(a_tag,"html5lib") #pip install html5lib
print(soup.find("a").get("href"))

#output - > http://twitter.com/download/iphone
```

Then use this function to remove the html and the text will be left

```
import re

def remove_html_tags(raw_html):
    cleanr = re.compile("<.*?>")
    clean_text = re.sub(cleanr,'',raw_html)

    return clean_text


output = remove_html_tags(a_tag)
print(output)

#output -> Twitter for iPhone
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python [urlextract](https://pypi.org/project/urlextract/) module to extract URLs from any string-

```
from urlextract import URLExtract

text = '''
<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>
'''
text = text.replace(' ', '').replace('=','')
extractor = URLExtract()
print(extractor.find_urls(text))
```

Output-

```
['http://twitter.com/download/iphone']
```

Answer (score -1):

You could split in '"'. And take the second element.

```
.split('"')[1]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split